# rancher - help on getting NFS working - volumeDriver.create: failed

Tags: nfs, rancher

I've installed NFS 0.30 (last version) stack using catalog.
The options are:

```
MOUNT_DIR   / 
MOUNT_OPTS    proto=tcp,port=2049,nfsvers=4 
NFS_SERVER    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (digitalocean droplet public ip)
```

The container starts normally and seems to be working fine. So, then I try to create a simple stack using the NFS with this docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
    - bar:/var/bar

volumes:
  bar:
    driver: rancher-nfs
```

And I get this error:

`(Expected state running but got error: Error response from daemon: create aaaa_bar_8fa9a: VolumeDriver.Create: Failed nsenter -t 11437 -n mount -o proto=tcp,port=2049,nfsvers=4 xx.xx.xx.xx:/ /tmp/5ht8d)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all the last version of NFS is `4.2` and the last version of the catalog is `v0.4.0`.

with the variable `MOUNT_DIR` you define where is the export point on your server, you are sure you want mount in the root dir?

You have create [NFS export](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-nfs-server-config-exports.html)?

After a NFS Export is created test by upgrading your service with new variable mount point (for example `/mnt/<environment_name>/`)